# Description with labels at the margin

Tags: lists, description

I am working on a "book" class, which means that the margins are on the right for odd pages and on the left for even pages. My goal would be to write a description list in which the labels are automatically put in the margins, and where the description of the item itself is in the main body. I tried many different ways so far but with no success. This is the best I was able to get, which works only for the pages with a left margin:

```
\documentclass[symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedright]{book} 
    \usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
This is the first page with a margin on the right: my code does not work!
\setlist[description]{font=\normalfont}
\begin{description} [align=right]
    \item [\protect{\parbox[t]{4.3cm}{\textbf{Concept}}}]
        \textbf{Description}
    \item [\protect{\parbox[t]{4.3cm}{This is the first item I want to describe}}]
        \protect{\parbox[t]{10cm}{This is the description of the first item.}}
    \item [\protect{\parbox[t]{4.3cm}{This is the second item I want to describe}}]
        \protect{\parbox[t]{10cm}{This is the description of the second item, which is normally longer than only one line.}}
\end{description}
This is the normal text bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.
\newpage    
This is the second page where my code is giving an acceptable result.
\setlist[description]{font=\normalfont}
\begin{description} [align=right]
    \item [\protect{\parbox[t]{4.3cm}{\textbf{Concept}}}]
        \textbf{Description}
    \item [\protect{\parbox[t]{4.3cm}{This is the first item I want to describe}}]
        \protect{\parbox[t]{10cm}{This is the description of the first item.}}
    \item [\protect{\parbox[t]{4.3cm}{This is the second item I want to describe}}]
        \protect{\parbox[t]{10cm}{This is the description of the second item, which is normally longer than only one line.}}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

This is the corresponding output:

[image]

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide a MWE.

Comment: Look in the answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution. I defined a `margindescription` clone of description, with specific parameters, and a `\mitem` command which does all you want, I think:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twosided]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[showframe, twoside, marginpar=3cm, outer = 36mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[fulladjust]{marginnote}
\newcommand\mitem[1][]{\item[\vphantom{\parbox{3cm}{#1\vspace*{\itemsep}}}]\marginnote{#1}}
\newlist{margindescription}{description}{1}

\setlist[margindescription]{labelsep=0pt, font=\normalfont,after =\vspace*{\dimexpr\topsep + \partopsep + \itemsep\relax}}

\begin{document}

\begin{margindescription}% [labelsep=0pt, font=\normalfont,after =\vspace*{\dimexpr\topsep + \partopsep + \itemsep\relax}]%after ={\item[]}
  \mitem[\bfseries Concept]
  \textbf{Description}
  \mitem [This is the first item I want to describe]
This is the description of the first item.
  \mitem [This is the second item I want to describe]
  This is the description of the second item, which is normally longer than only one line.
\end{margindescription}
This is the normal text bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

\begin{description} [font=\normalfont]%
  \item[\bfseries Concept]
  \textbf{Description}
  \item [This is the first item I want to describe]
This is the description of the first item.
  \item [This is the second item I want to describe]
  This is the description of the second item, which is normally longer than only one line.
\end{description}
This is normal text bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla. \newpage
\begin{description} [labelsep=0pt, font=\normalfont]%
  \mitem[\bfseries Concept]
  \textbf{Description}
  \mitem [This is the first item I want to describe]
  This is the description of the first item.
  \mitem [This is the second item I want to describe]
 This is the description of the second item, which is normally longer than only one line.
\end{description}
This is normal text bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla. 
\end{document}
```

Resulting two pages:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank You Bernard, but unfortunately Your solution does not work for odd pages in which the margin is on the right side. I would like to create a command that recognizes even pages than odd pages.

Comment: I don't quite follow you: I tested on an `odd` page, and there are always two margins. Do you mean you want the description label in the right margin on odd pages and in the left margin on even pages – in other words, it should always be in the *outer* margin?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want: description label in the right margin on odd pages and in the left margin on even pages. I also tried by using the \marginpar command but did not succeed.

Comment: @Francesca: I think I have a solution, with the help of the `marginnote` package. Is it closer to what you want?